Ray tracing working in Mac, but not on Windows
Here is a working Mathematica code for a 3d plot:
potential = 
 Plot3D[-{-(2.16023) x^2 - (6.26501) y^2 + (2.54649) x^3 + (21.1988) \
x y^2}, {x, 0, 0.5}, {y, -0.2, 0.2}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> {Cyan, Opacity[0.7]}, ViewPoint -> {1, -1.75, 1}, 
  Mesh -> None, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "V"}, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[.005], ImageSize -> 500, ImageMargins -> 10, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 20]]

which gives me the following output:

Now, I wish to make some aesthetic shadow work beneath, for which I take the help of this piece of code:
a = Style[
  Graphics3D[{First[potential], White, 
    Polygon[5 {{-0.1, -0.1, 0}, {-0.1, 0.1, 0}, {0.1, 0.1, 
         0}, {0.1, -0.1, 0}} + Threaded[{0, 0, -0.3}]]}, 
   Lighting -> {AmbientLight[RGBColor[0.2, 0.2, 0.2]], {"Area", 
      RGBColor[0.65, 0.65, 0.65], {0, 0, 
       18}, {{4, 0, 0}, {0, 4, 0}}}}, Boxed -> False, 
   ViewPoint -> {2, -1.75, 1.05}, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"RayTracing" -> {"ImageSamples" -> 150, 
       "RayBounce" -> 2}}], 
  RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingMethod" -> "RayTracing"}]

This gives me two different outputs when run on MacOS and Windows; here is a comparison:

Why is the RayTracing option not working on Windows, and is there any workaround for that? Also, how to include the axes in the shadow figure as well? Is there a way by which I can get something like this figure(showing the stationary points) with a blurry shadow beneath it?


This also failed on the Wolfram Cloud (14.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 13, 2023))

To see the axes include the option Axes -> True (and delete Boxed -> False if you also want the box).

It is an undocumented/highly experimental feature.  It is so experimental, it has only been implemented on Mac using Metal.  I do not have a timeframe for when it might be elevated to an experimental (yet documented) feature.

Is there any workaround for now?

Other than not using ray tracing?  No.
